# Why i cant open new angular project when my node.js & npm both are updated?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am new to Angular. I have installed node.js with npm latest version & then Angular CLI.then I write this in node.js command prompt

```
ng new my-app
```

but then I get this!!

[image]

what did I do wrong??

Comment: It's not an error its a warning. You can ignore that and start working

Answer (score 0):

It' not a critical issue.
You can try `npm update` command and I hope that warning will get removed
.